# How do I trigger scripts on a merge or when a branch is deleted?

Tags: jenkins, git, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkinsfile

I  am using jenkins multibranch pipelines. If a branch is merged and deleted jenkins removes the branch from the pipeline as well.

This is great, but I want to run a command/script when a branch is removed, how can I have jenkins run a command when a branch is removed? Is there a way to have jenkins trigger a job before it removes the branch?

Edit: I should add I'm using bitbucket. It would be neat if Jenkins could trigger an event when purging a branch of a multibranch pipeline. Ideally it wouldn't matter what my git provider is.

Comment: For Bitbucket: https://dengelonsoftware.blogspot.fi/2017/01/jenkins-pull-request-and-pipeline.html?m=1

Comment: How about webhooks?https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-webhooks-735643732.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"This is great, but I want to run a command/script when a branch is removed, how can I have jenkins run a command when a branch is removed?"*

> You will need to use a **webhook** for this, I use the following
>   settings in Github:

[image]

> **Bitbucket** only supports the following webhooks:

[image]

*"Is there a way to have Jenkins trigger a job before it removes the branch?"*

> Not that I can see, but in Github you can create a custom label and
>   trigger a job via a webhook when the label is added to a branch.

Comment: Ok but how do you detect in Jenkins that you're building because of a branch deletion vs a push to the branch?